# Reload the Map when we navigate to MapTabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a tabBarView controller and a TableViewController. When I click on a row I wan to go to another Tab which is UIViewController with Map:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if(storeName) 
       [self setMap];
}

- (void) setMap {

    NSLog(@"Name:%@\n", storeName);
    NSLog(@"Adress:%@\n", storeAddress);



        self.indexMapView.delegate = self;

        self.indexMapView.showsUserLocation = NO;

        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [locationManager setDelegate:self];

        [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

        [self.indexMapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self getLocationFromAddressString:self.storeAddress];

        NSLog(@"%g", location.latitude);

        MapViewAnnotation *mapAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Store location" coordinate:location];
        [self.indexMapView addAnnotation:mapAnnotation];

}

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocationFromAddressString:(NSString*) addressStr {

    NSLog(@"FFF");

    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",
                        [addressStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSString *locationStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    NSArray *items = [locationStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    double lat = 0.0;
    double lon = 0.0;

    if([items count] >= 4 && [[items objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
        lat = [[items objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        lon = [[items objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Address, %@ not found: Error %@",addressStr, [items objectAtIndex:0]);
    }

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = lat;
    location.longitude = lon;

    return location;
}
```

This is how I go to the MapViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MapViewController *mapViewController = [[MapViewController alloc]init];

    [mapViewController setStoreAddress:store.address];
    [mapViewController setStoreName:store.name];
    [mapViewController viewDidLoad];

    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:4];
}
```

The problem is Map does not get update when I go to the page again. When I tried it with `PushSegue`, it works. but how can I make it work with TabBar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how can I pass the data over tab bars. You can find more descriptions in these links:

[iPhone: How to Pass Data Between Several Viewcontrollers in a Tabbar App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363777/iphone-how-to-pass-data-between-several-viewcontrollers-in-a-tabbar-app)

[Passing a managedObjectContext through to a UITabBarController's views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970952/passing-a-managedobjectcontext-through-to-a-uitabbarcontrollers-views)

Also [this tutorial](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/iOS-5-How-To-Share-Data-Between-View-Controllers-using-a-Singleton) is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you commented out your call to `-setMap`, which means that when the view loads, nothing of interest is going to happen. Was that intentional?

Comment: I used setMap when user clicks on a row in another TableViewController.

Comment: check the code for `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)`

Comment: Ah, but your view is *not yet loaded* when you do that.

Comment: So what should I do? I know how to make it work with `prepare for segue`. but not with the tabBar. Can you help me in the code?

Comment: You should be doing this view setup in `-viewDidLoad`. Prior to iOS 6, that method can be called multiple times, and each time you have to do the setup again.

Comment: I could not make it work with your suggestion. You can see my edit in the code.